# Truncate Timespan after two decimal places

Tags: c#

I have a timespan that displays as such: `7.43053333333333`. My goal is to simply display it as `7.43`.

How would I truncate two the second value after the decimal place. I tried using `Math.Round` instead of truncating, but it would simnple return `7`

Comment: Possibly importantly, do you want to truncate this (i.e. always round down), or do you just want to round to 2 DP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just  use [`Math.Round Method (Decimal, Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
double d = 7.43053333333333;
double ma = Math.Round(d, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and supply number of digits to round

```
double roundedValue = Math.Round(7.43053333333333, 2);
```

You will get back `7.43`

Answer (score 1):

> How would I **truncate** two the second value after the decimal place.

if you just want to truncate the double value to get 2 digits after precision.

Try This:

```
double d = 7.43053333333333;
String s = d.ToString("N2");
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Math.Round()` like following

```
Math.Round(7.43053333333333, 2);
```